# Reduce memory footprint of python program

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm developing a data analysis worker in python using numpy and pandas. I will deploy lots of these workers so I want to keep it lightweight.

I tried checking with this code:

```
import logging
import resource
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def printmemory(msg):
    currentmemory = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    logging.debug(msg+': total memory:%r Mb' % (int(currentmemory)/1000000.))

printmemory('begin')

#from numpy import array, nan, mean, std, sqrt, square
import numpy  as np
printmemory('numpy')

import pandas  as pd
printmemory('numpy')
```

and I found out that simply loading them to memory will make my worker pretty heavy. Is there a way to reduce the memory footprint of numpy and pandas?

Otherwise, any suggestion on a better solution?

Comment: You can reduce it a bit by only importing the methods and classes you need from each library. EG. if I'm only using pandas DataFrame, then instead of "import pandas" use "from pandas import DataFrame".

Comment: why do you give msg as argument, while you dont do anything with it?

Comment: Edited. It was a copy/paste from a previous edit. @RyanG As you can see there's a commented line that does exactly that, but it didn't seem to affect memory usage at all...

Comment: Then there is no way to reduce the memory usage if the select methods/classes are also importing the entire library/other libraries as well. The only option you may have is to setup your data structures to be light weight so each worker isn't boated by redundant copies of the same data or excessive amounts of data which might be better off split across different workers. Of course this will depend on your environment. If you have more cores then more smaller workers will make sense, but if you have a high amount of memory, then bulking wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I think with a modern computer with reasonable ram loading the entire numpy library along with pandas should be the least of your concerns. I guess if you really want to make it more lightweight, you need to think about how to get only the data into the ram you are actually using. I've heard that pytables are actually really good at that although I've not worked with those myself. If you "just" want to make use of parralelization you might want to look into Cython where you can use the "prange" that will parallelize your loops and it will give you C-speed.

Comment: I am not trying to make it go faster, I could use Cython or Numba for that. I'm trying to make it so that each worker doesn't have to load it's own copy of Numpy in memory. I would like to to have Numpy loaded only once and then all the workers can access it. The ideas I thought to do this are: 1) change program architecture. Workers are no longer independent scripts. 2) turn on memory de-duplication on the host. Other ideas?

Comment: steering clear of pandas entirely can also be pretty lightweight. it's crazy how fast sets, dictionaries, and lists can be. loops might not be sexy -- but they work!

Comment: On Linux at least, shared libraries will only be loaded once into physical memory. For instance, if I load the full bulk of matplotlib, numpy and pandas, the main process uses 50M more than the subprocess.

Comment: Could use some more info on your analysis re "make my worker pretty heavy" -- what was the memory consumption, how did you measure it, what's you baseline for comparison?

Comment: On my Linux box, importing numpy (1.9.1) took 6.58MB and importing Pandas (0.15.2) took 22.3MB more. However, `from pandas import DataFrame` took no less memory.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to tell you, but there is no way to load into memory only a part of a python module. You could use multi-threading if that applies to your case - threads can share the same module memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of what problem you want to tackle, but if you need to paralellize numpy, maybe pycuda could be something for you. numpy and pandas works perfectly when being paralellized in cuda, but numpy would only be loaded once in memory, but fired in multiple processes in the graphics card.
Read some more about it here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/pycuda